# How to check for only checked checkboxes in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, code.org

I am using `code.org` library. I am trying to use only checked checkboxes to select two teams for a baseball game. Currently I can only select 1 team but I need to select two teams effectively by not just going to the next team in the `array`. I have never see such problem in `JavaScript`.

```
onEvent("btnStart","click", function() {
    var chkBoxs = ["Yankees","Boston","Astros"];
    var index = 0;
    while (index < chkBoxs.length && !getChecked(chkBoxs[index])) {
      index++;
    }
    setScreen("game");
    console.log("The Teams are: " + chkBoxs[index]+" And "+chkBoxs[index+1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the selected ones in a new array.

Also, remember to check that you have succeeded in finding two before you let your program continue.

Example:

```
onEvent("btnStart","click", function() {
    var chkBoxs = ["Yankees","Boston","Astros"];
    var selected = [];
    for (index = 0; selected.length < 2 && index < chkBoxs.length; index++) {
        if (getChecked(chkBoxs[index])) { selected.push(index); }
    }
    setScreen("game");
    if (selected.length == 2) {
        console.log("The Teams are: " + chkBoxs[selected[0]] + " and " + chkBoxs[selected[1]]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question, you could keep track of the selected teams individually using an array:

```
onEvent("btnStart","click", function() {
    var chkBoxs = ["Yankees","Boston","Astros"];
    var indexes = [];
    for (var i =0; i < chkBoxs.length; i++) {
       if (getChecked(chkBoxs[index]))) {
          indexes.push(index); // store team index
       } 
    }
    setScreen("game");
    console.log("The Teams are: " + chkBoxs[indexes[0]]+" And "+chkBoxs[indexes[1]]);
});
```

This also assumes you always have two teams. Otherwise you'd have to handle the last line differently. If all you need is the team name:

```
onEvent("btnStart","click", function() {
    var chkBoxs = ["Yankees","Boston","Astros"];
    var teams = [];
    for (var i =0; i < chkBoxs.length; i++) {
       if (getChecked(chkBoxs[index]))) {
          teams.push(chkBoxs[index]); // store team name
       } 
    }
    setScreen("game");
    console.log("The Teams are: " + teams.join(', ') + ".");
});
```